# nicEdit dynamical instances binding 2 of the functions

Tags: javascript, html, nicedit

I have read all the answers provided on this questions and none of them are applying to my needs.

Also, i have already asked an 'almost similar' question about binding on dynamically created elements. I also applied these answers (which worked on other scripts) but it does not work on this one.

Explanation:

I have a form, where i give the possiblity to add a new row to my table (row with multiple cells) one of these cell is a textarea. What i want to do is be able to add nicedit to these text area created dynamically.

The creation of the new row and cells:

```
    var index = 2;

function myCreateFunction() {

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = "<textarea type='text' id='des" + index + "' name='des" + index + "' placeholder='' rows='1' class='form-control input-sm' value=''/></textarea>";
cell1.vAlign = "top";
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='qu" + index + "' name='qu" + index + "' placeholder='' class='form-control input-sm qu' value=''/>";
cell2.vAlign = "top";
cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='pu" + index + "' name='pu" + index + "' placeholder='' class='form-control input-sm pu' value=''/>";
cell3.vAlign = "top";
cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='rl" + index + "' name='rl" + index + "' placeholder='' class='form-control input-sm rl' value=''/>";
cell4.vAlign = "top";
cell5.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='tl" + index + "' name='tl" + index + "' placeholder='' class='form-control input-sm total' value=''/>";
cell5.vAlign = "top";
index++;
return false;
```

Each clic adds a row and the textarea is on the first cell

Now the nicedit with instances:

```
                                 bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
                                      var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
                                      myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des1');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des2');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des3');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des4');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des5');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des6');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des7');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des8');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des9');
                                      myNicEditor.addInstance('des10');
                                 });
```

Only the instance "des1" is preloaded on the page and nicedit works perfectly, if i clic add row, it will created a row with the id and class "des2" but the nicedit does not apply to it.

This is what i have tried, please no laughing, i am still limited in the comprehension of javascript:

I wrape nicedit loading into a function:

```
function addnicedit {

//nicedit code here

}
$("#myTable").on("change", addnicedit);
```

I thought of generating this nicEdit code each time #mytable gets a modification (new row added) and run the nicedit function each time the new row is created. But here, the nicedit does not even load once.

I should mention that the nicEdit Panel is not loaded on each text area, i am using this exemple: http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=4 it is the inline editor where i have the panel loaded ONCE only and it should apply to all the textareas.

I would love some help with this, is it my code 'function' that is not written correctly or is it just not possible with nicEdit and the way it is loaded. I see also a onDomLoaded elements in the code... is there something realted to that ?

Any help is mucly appreciated.

Thanks for reading :)

> Update

I tried re-initializing the nicedit function each time the row is created like this:

the nicedit function has no names so i gave it a name (tried)

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function initNicEdit() {
                                  var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
                                  myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
                                 // instances
                             });
```

And re-run the function initNicEdit() at the end of my function which adds a row like this:

```
function myCreateFunction() {
//function here
index++;
initNicEdit();
return false;
```

But i can not see the effect since the page refreshes. I did have return false; at the end of my function, also in initNicEdit(); and on my button, but it does still refresh.

I'll keep trying.

Comment: Have you tried myNicEditor.addInstance() in myCreateFunction() after adding the textarea?

Comment: Just did, it does the same issue, it keeps refreshing the page so i can not see the result:

I added the instance after my code, i hit the button, it adds the line but the page refreshes :/

Comment: You must work with a global var MynicEditor. And you can only add an Instance that exists. For that what you will do, you need some javascript experience. The page refresh after you add myNicEditor.addInstance() in myCreateFunction()?

Comment: Yes the page refreshes.